# MIPS Recursive String Length?

Tags: assembly, mips

I am currently trying to implement a recursive function to calculate the length of the string in MIPS. Heres the code I have right now. I am struggling to figure out the base case and how to get it to return the string length. I feel like I am very close as when I step through the program, it correctly counts and stores the length of the string entered. Any help is appreciated:

```
.text
#.align 2


main:
la $a0, input #load string for user input
li $v0, 4 #command to print string in syscall
syscall 

li $v0, 8 #command to take user input 
la $a0, buffer #store string of user input in buffer
li $a1,256 #length of buffer for string
    syscall


move $t0,$a0 #move string address to $t0

addi $t2,$t2,0 #initialize word length counter

addi $sp, $sp, -16 #allocate space in stack
sw $t0,16($sp) #store string address in stack, which will be the working string 
    sw $ra,12($sp) #save return address 
    sw $t2,8($sp) #save word length counter
    jal reclength


    # if we get here then the string is finished 

reclength:
    lw $t0,16($sp) #load word from stack and store address in $t0
    lw $t1,8($sp) #load counter from stack and store in $t1
    lbu $t2,0($t0) #get first bit from word in position 0 of address stored in $t0

    ## BASE CASE ##
    beq $t2,$zero,finisher

    ## RECURSIVE CASE ##
    addi $t1,$t1,1 #incremement length counter
    addi $t0,$t0,1 #point to the next character

    addi $sp, $sp, -16
    sw $t1,8($sp) #store the counter in the stack
    sw $ra,12($sp) #store the return address in the stack
    sw $t0,16($sp) #store new address in stack
    jal reclength



    #jr $ra
    #nop


finisher:
lw $t1,8($sp) #load counter from stack
addi $t1,$t1,-1 #decrement counter because null counter was counted
la $a0, ending #load string for user input
    li $v0, 4 #command to print string in syscall
    syscall 
jr $ra







.data
#.align 2
input:   .asciiz "Enter a string : " 
buffer:  .space 256
ending:  .asciiz "Finished"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You keep moving the stack pointer "downward" for each function call you make, but you never adjust it upward as you return.

I found the whole design with having the return value on the stack a bit peculiar. Typically one would use `$v0` to return the value of a function. So I'd rewrite the function like this:

```
reclength:
    lw $t0,12($sp)  # load string address from stack and place it in $t0
    lbu $t2,0($t0)  # read one byte from the string and place it in $t2

    bne $t2,$zero,recurse
    li $v0, 0       # base case : length = 0
    j return

recurse:
    # recursive case : return reclength(addr+1) + 1
    addi $t0,$t0,1 # point to the next character

    addi $sp, $sp, -16
    sw $ra,8($sp)  # store the return address in the stack
    sw $t0,12($sp) # store new address in stack
    jal reclength
    addi $v0,$v0,1 

return:
    lw $ra, 8($sp)  # restore the return address
    addiu $sp,$sp,16 # restore the stack pointer
    jr $ra
```

Which you would call like this:

```
addi $sp, $sp, -16 #allocate space in stack
sw $t0,12($sp) #store string address in stack, which will be the working string 
sw $ra,8($sp) #save return address 
jal reclength
```

You could get rid of having the string address on the stack as well, and use `$a0` for that instead. But I'll leave that as an exercise for you.

You may also want to exit the program properly once `reclength` returns to `main`:

```
li $v0,10  # syscall 10 = exit
syscall
```